# The display is not changing according to selected option

Tags: javascript, html, css

These are extracts of code related to the problem mentioned in the Title. Please help. Thank you.(At the beginning div id="1" is being displayed, and it is still displayed as the selected options are being changed.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>CourseID-<?php echo $_POST['kp']."-Self Test ".$_POST['tn'];</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/[version]/jquery.mobile-[version].min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-[version].min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/[version]/jquery.mobile-[version].min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayType()
{

var e = document.getElementById("ansType");
var check = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  if(check=="T")
  {
      document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("2").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("4").style.display = "none";
  }
  else if(check=="D")
  {
      document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("3").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("4").style.display = "none";
  }
  else if(check=="TD")
  {
      document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("4").style.display = "block";
  }
  else
  {
      document.getElementById("1").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("4").style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="" enctype="">
<div class="form-group">
<div id="buttons">
  <label for="sel1" id="selside">INPUT TYPE (select one):</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="ansType" style="width:300px;" onchange="displayType()">
        <option value="M">A</option>
        <option value="T">B</option>
        <option value="D">C</option>
        <option value="TD">D</option>
      </select>
<br><br>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display">
<div id="1" style="display:block">
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o1"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt1"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt2"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt3"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt4"></label>
</div>
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none">
<div id="area"><textarea cols="100" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea><div><br>
</div>

<div id="3" style="display:none">
<div id="up"><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></button></div>
</div>

<div id="4" style="display:none">
<div id="area"><textarea cols="100" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea><div><br>
<div id="up"><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></button></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It’s a typo. Use `document.getElementById("testtype")` instead of `document.getElementById("testType")`. Or you change the ID to `testType`, of course.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work

Comment: var e = document.getElementById("testtype");
            var check = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; put that code before if condition.also you need to put CDN.

Comment: [Xufox](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/xufox) - Thank you Xufox . I have changed my problem now . Please see  if you can solve it.

Comment: [kirtan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5748011/kirtan) - Thank you Kirtan - I have edited my problem now - Please see if you can solve it - Thank you again

Comment: You're missing a `?>` to close that `<?php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change `testType` to `testtype`.

You can also get the value of dropdown like this

```
var e = document.getElementById("testtype");
var check = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

```js
function displayType()
{
 
var e = document.getElementById("anstype");
var check = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  
  if(check=="T")
  {
      document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("2").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("4").style.display = "none";
  }
  else if(check=="D")
  {
      document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("3").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("4").style.display = "none";
  }
  else if(check=="TD")
  {
      document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("4").style.display = "block";
  }
  else
  {
      document.getElementById("1").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("2").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("3").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("4").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="" enctype="">
<div class="form-group">
<div id="buttons">
  <label for="sel1" id="selside">INPUT TYPE (select one):</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="anstype" style="width:300px;" onchange="displayType()">
        <option value="M">A</option>
        <option value="T">B</option>
        <option value="D">C</option>
        <option value="TD">D</option>
      </select>
<br><br>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display">
<div id="1" style="display:block">
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o1"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt1"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt2"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt3"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt4"></label>
</div>
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none">
<div id="area"><textarea cols="100" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea></div><br>
</div>

<div id="3" style="display:none">
<div id="up"><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></div>
</div>

<div id="4" style="display:none">
<div id="area"><textarea cols="100" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea></div><br>
<div id="up"><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></div>
</div>
  
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Update**: It was because you have not closed your `divs` and `inputs` rightly.

Comment: [Alorika](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5619896/alorika) - Thank you- I have edited my problem - it does not work, but my previous problem was solved - Thanks a lot

Comment: [Alorika](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5619896/alorika) - The code that I have posted just now doesn't work to change the display according to selected option - Thank you

Comment: As I can see your code, you have values 'M, T, D, TD' but in your script you have put checks for 'T,TH,F'. Considering these checks, it is working fine. So you need to check the values in the dropdown with the condition you are trying to match. Please check and let me know

Comment: [Alorika](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5619896/alorika)  - It seems that div id="3" and div id="4" are showing nothing

Comment: 'C' is showing input type file and 'D' is showing a text area and input type file in the above snippet. Check the screenshots here http://snag.gy/o0jwD.jpg and http://snag.gy/tuUnp.jpg

Comment: [Alorika](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5619896/alorika) - Thanks a lot Alorika - Have Solved the problem - would like to ask you how to center div  id="1"  instead of letting it appear on the left 0- Thank you again

Answer (score -1):

```js
function displayType() {
  var check = $('#testtype').val();
  $('.outcome').hide();
  
  if(check=="T") {
    $('#2').show();
  }
  else if(check=="TH") {
      $('#3').show();
  }
  else if(check=="F") {
     $('#4').show();
  }
  else {
     $('#1').show();
  }
}
```

```css
.outcome {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="sel1" id="selside">Testing Type (select one):</label>
<select class="form-control" id="testtype" style="width:300px;" onchange="displayType()">
  <option value="O">1</option>
  <option value="T">2</option>
  <option value="TH">3</option>
  <option value="F">4</option>
</select>

<div id="display">
<div id="1" class="outcome active">
Testing1
</div>

<div id="2" class="outcome">
Testing2
</div>

<div id="3" class="outcome">
Testing3
</div>

<div id="4" class="outcome">
Testing4
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Nick De Jaeger](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1989960/nick-de-jaeger) - Thank you for helping Nick - I have edited my problem - Please see if you have a solution to this - Thank you again